# Azure Web app - Could not resolve the hostname into a valid IP address

Tags: facebook, azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I'm having a problem using Facebook object debugger ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ ) to scrape information from my page and i'm
getting the error "Could not resolve the hostname into a valid IP address." as you can see bellow

[image: Facebook scrapping information]

This website hosted in Azure, as an Web App.

Everything looks ok on the domain registrar, i have an A record pointing to the public IP and a CNAME pointing to xxx.azurewebsites.net.

Comment: How long have you been trying and when did you set up the CNAME? The hostname from your picture resolves fine for me. The only thing which comes to my mind is that the server saw the old value before your change and couldn't resolve it. I don't know what was your original TTL, but the current one is 86400 seconds (1 day), so I wouldn't be surprised if the issue got resolved on its own in 24 hours since you made the change.

Comment: Hey Petr, the configurations were done about a week ago. The host does resolve fine to me, except for the Facebook scrapper. I removed the A record last night to try viperguynaz suggestion, which didn't work. .

Comment: Then I'm afraid you will need to contact the Facebook support so they can take a look. Maybe they cached something on their side.

Comment: will do Petr, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try removing the A record and redirecting the root to www.

Comment: I did remove the A record and the result is still the same.